# Bootstrap Button active color change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap button class, more specifically the following :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Login</button>
```

Right now, the color is showing green which is fine. Every time I click the button, the button changes into a darkish shade of green. What I want is to make it so that the button does not change color but just remain the default bootstrap color and also, remove the blue outline around it.

For the blue outline, I attempted setting the outline to none but it didn't work for some reason. I know we have to use

```
.btn : active:focus {

}
```

But I don't know the default color of the bootstrap success button so I'm having difficulty in figuring it out.

Comment: To override Bootstrap's css, you have to call `!important`. Just make sure you won't need to override the class again before doing so.

Comment: so for the outline I would have to do outline: none !important 

@DrewKennedy

Comment: Give it a try and see what happens, then let us know. :)

Comment: @DrewKennedy That's not necessarily true. Giving the CSS rule a higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) would override the default Bootstrap styling without the use of `!important`.

Answer (score 17):

The default color for `btn-success` is **#5cb85c**. All you have to do is inspect it with DevTools or search your bootstrap stylesheet to find all the rules that pertain to this class and change whatever you need in your own stylesheet to override them. No need to use `!important` at all, specificity is your friend. See [MDN Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

See working Snippet (This example changed all states to the same base color just as an example and also removes the box-shadow property as well. You should be able to change whatever you need from here.)

```css
.btn.btn-success {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}
.btn.btn-success.focus,
.btn.btn-success:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn.btn-success:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.btn.btn-success.active,
.btn.btn-success:active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  outline: none;
}
.btn.btn-success.active.focus,
.btn.btn-success.active:focus,
.btn.btn-success.active:hover,
.btn.btn-success:active.focus,
.btn.btn-success:active:focus,
.btn.btn-success:active:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  border-color: #5cb85c;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Changed BTN</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Default BTN</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the original style settings for the `btn-success` and noticed there are four colors. I extracted them and rotated the hues. I then replaced all of the corresponding colors.

[image]

```js
/**

Original colors
===============
#28a745
#218838 <-- rgba(40, 167, 69, 0.5)
#1e7e34
#1c7430

Updated colors
===============
#8a458f
#703975 <-- rgba(112, 57, 117, 0.5)
#69346c
#613064

*/
```

```css
.btn.btn-success {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #8a458f;
  border-color: #8a458f;
}
.btn.btn-success:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #703874;
  border-color: #69346d;
}
.btn.btn-success:focus, .btn.btn-success.focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(112, 56, 116, 0.5);
}
.btn.btn-success.disabled, .btn.btn-success:disabled {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #8a458f;
  border-color: #8a458f;
}
.btn.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.btn.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #69346d;
  border-color: #613064;
}
.show > .btn.btn-success.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #69346d;
  border-color: #613064;
}
.show > .btn.btn-success.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(112, 56, 116, 0.5);
}
.btn.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,
.btn.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(112, 56, 116, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-btn">Modified Button</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">Regular Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Here is the SASS that I reverse-engineered.

```
/** SASS */
$color-text: #ffffff
$color-highlight: #8a458f
$color-light: darken($color-highlight, 7.8%)                // #703874
$color-dark: darken($color-highlight, 10.0%)                // #69346d
$color-shadow: darken($color-highlight, 12.5%)              // #613064
$box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem transparentize($color-light, 0.5) // rgba(112, 56, 116, 0.5)

.btn.btn-success
  color: $color-text
  background-color: $color-highlight
  border-color: $color-highlight
  &:hover
    color: $color-text
    background-color: $color-light
    border-color: $color-dark
  &:focus, &.focus
    box-shadow: $box-shadow
  &.disabled, &:disabled
    color: $color-text
    background-color: $color-highlight
    border-color: $color-highlight
  &:not(:disabled):not(.disabled)
    &:active, &.active
      color: $color-text
      background-color: $color-dark
      border-color: $color-shadow
.show
  >.btn.btn-success.dropdown-toggle
    color: $color-text
    background-color: $color-dark
    border-color: $color-shadow
  >.btn.btn-success.dropdown-toggle:focus
    box-shadow: $box-shadow
.btn.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled)
  &:active:focus, &.active:focus
    box-shadow: $box-shadow
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  The color pallet example really helped me organize my changes.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Just got a notification, I updated this to use `darken` instead of "making up" color values.

Comment: You are the man!  I actually have about 3 different "styles" that I have to do and still haven't done them yet.  This is seriously helpful.  I hope everyone scrolls to this answer, instead, as I did.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, out of curiosity, how did you generate your shifted hues? For example, did you take the base color and shade it 10% each time? And did you use a tool [like this](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-reference/html-color-picker.php), or did you calculate the colors yourself (if so, what were your calculations)? Thanks!

Comment: @JoelBalmer it's been 2 years, but I think I just took all the colors from the source button and just rotated the hues. I then used GIMP to extract the hex values.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yeah it's been a whiles, sorry :) I was just wondering what exactly you mean by/what you did when you say hue rotation.

Comment: @JoelBalmer I rotated the hue. Instead of RGB, I used HSV and rotated the H channel by a particular amount.

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing around with this and the other answers and in Bootstrap 4.3, this is all I had to do:

```
.btn.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn.btn-primary:hover {
    border-color: $color-primary;
    background-color: $color-primary;
    // color: $color-primary;
}
```